# How can I match the values of multiple variables according to the dates of a variable of interest and summarise them alone in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this :

| var | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| A | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| A | 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| A | 2022-01-04 | 4 |
| A | 2022-01-05 | 5 |
| A | 2022-01-06 | 6 |
| A | 2022-01-07 | 7 |
| B | 2022-02-02 | 10 |
| B | 2022-01-03 | 20 |
| B | 2022-01-07 | 30 |
| C | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| C | 2022-01-04 | 200 |
| C | 2022-01-05 | 300 |
| C | 2022-06-06 | 400 |

My variable of interest is the A from column var.Specifically the dates of A that match the values of the other factors inn var variable.I want to pivot wider them into :

| date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | NA | 100 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | NA | NA |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 | 20 | NA |
| 2022-01-04 | 4 | NA | 200 |
| 2022-01-05 | 5 | NA | 300 |
| 2022-01-06 | 6 | NA | NA |
| 2022-01-07 | 7 | 30 | NA |

And at the end to each column to summarize the sum (or even the correlation of A with B and the correlation A with C):

| var | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| A | 28 |
| B | 50 |
| C | 600 |

How can I do it in R using dplyr package ?

```
library(tidyverse)
date = c(seq(as.Date("2022/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 7),
      as.Date("2022/2/2"),as.Date("2022/1/3"),as.Date("2022/1/7"),
      as.Date("2022/1/1"),as.Date("2022/1/4"),as.Date("2022/1/5"),as.Date("2022/6/6"))
var = c(rep("A",7),rep("B",3),rep("C",4))
value = c(seq(1,7,1),10,20,30,100,200,300,400)
data = tibble(var,date,value);data
```

Comment: Perhaps `pivot_wider(data, names_from = var, values_from = value) %>% filter(!is.na(A))`; and `data %>% group_by(var) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(value))`

Comment: nope.It sums all the values column wise.I want only the matching to dates values.It has to by group_by columns

Comment: Maybe your example gets the same output as expected when we use the full data

Comment: I get `pivot_wider(data, names_from = var, values_from = value) %>% filter(!is.na(A)) %>% summarise(across(A:C, sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'var', values_to = 'Sum')## A tibble: 3 × 2
  var     Sum
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A        28
2 B        50
3 C       600`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may convert to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`, `filter` out the NA element rows from `A` column`,` summarise across`the columns to get the`sum`and reshape to 'long' with`pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(data, names_from = var, values_from = value) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(A)) %>% 
   summarise(across(A:C, sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'var', values_to = 'Sum')
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  var     Sum
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A        28
2 B        50
3 C       600
```

Comment: If I had 100 columns ? how summarize will change ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson.  you can change `across(A:C` to `across(-date,` assuming 'date' is a column

Comment: if I exclude the date column there will remain only the columns (100 columns). and then ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson yes,  assuming original data have only 3 columns because `pivot_wider` returns all those 100 columns from the 'var' values

Comment: I wasn't clear. My question is how the A:C can be changed if I had 100 column in the summarize function? To be across all columns

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson I would say, after the `pivot_wider` step, you have 101 columns with the first one being the `date` columns.  So by doing `across(-date`, it is selecting all the other columns

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson or may also use `summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE))`